# Counting Number of Word in Each Sentence

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashtable, bufferedreader

I have a text file in this format:

```
   Word   index
   Adam     0
   likes    1
   to       2
   play     3
   soccer   4
   You      0
   have     1
   to       2
   study    3
   for      4
   the      5
   exam     6
```

I want to count the number of words in each sentence. I created 3 array lists one for the word index, other for counting the tokens in the sentence, and the other for saving the number of tokens for each sentence. I read the above file into array list and did the following:

```
    (int f=0; f<OnlyWordIndex.size() ;f++){
       if (!OnlyWordIndex.get(f).equals("0"))
        {
         NumberCounter1.add("1");
        }

        if (OnlyWordIndex.get(f).equals("0"))
        {
         NumberCounter1.add("1");
         SentenceLegnth=NumberCounter1.size();
         NumberCounter2.add(SentenceLegnth);
         NumberCounter1.clear();

        }
     }
```

But I think either I'm missing something or complicating the problem. So, any help in improving this will be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: What did you get for your output and what is your intended output?

Answer (score 0):

It seems logical to use a map in this case instead of an ArrayList even though you could implement in both ways.

Using a Map:

```
Map<String,Integer> wordMap = putWordsInMap(File file);

public void countWords([whatever-input-you-want]) {
    String sentence = [some-sentence];
    String[] senSplit = sentence.split(" ");
    for(String s : senSplit) {
        if(wordMap.contains(s)) {
            wordMap.put(s,new Integer(wordMap.get(s).intValue + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to also keep track of how many of the words were found in each sentence you'd add this to the existing code:

```
List<String> sentenceWords = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : senSplit) {    
if(wordMap.contains(s)) {    
    wordMap.put(s,new Integer(wordMap.get(s).intValue + 1));    
    sentenceWordCount += 1;
}  
sentenceWords.add(sentenceWordCount);
```

You could also implement the sentence word count as a map...it depends what context is behind the solution.